# How To play 25MB+ audio file directly from google drive in HTML 5?

Tags: php, html, google-drive-api, html5-audio

I am fetching 25+ MB Audio file from google drive.

I need to play this file using html5 code.

For this i am using below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio controls>
  <source src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1gAlyxjlHyaZldJTUZsTWwybGM/view"> 
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
 </audio>

 </body>
</html>
```

Using this code files which are below 25 MB plays properly. But if it is more then 25 MB then it wont. Please suggest any way to solve this point where i can play files which are more then 25 MB.
Thank you.

Comment: does an error occur anywhere when you try a larger file? It would be useful to clarify "won't play properly".

Comment: No, i can't find any error.

Comment: does it work if you host the same file yourself (on the same server as the html page)? We should ascertain whether Drive is the issue here, or the size of the file.

Comment: Yes,Google drive has an issue of size limit of allowing only 25 MB file. So is there any alternative way to do this task where i can play files of more than 25 MB.

Comment: Looking online I can't find any evidence of such a limitation on Drive - can you provide a reference? There used to be a 25MB size limit on GMail attachements, but that's not relevant to Drive. If your file is already in Drive and is bigger than 25MB, then clearly Drive doesn't have that storage limit. However, if hosting it there is stopping you playing it in a web page, then the simplest solution is to host it somewhere else.

Comment: in deed there is a limitation, but to understant what happens actually you have to paste that link right in the browser and try, you'll notice that for large files google shows a warning that it cannot scan it to detect viruses and gives a button to download anyway, thus requiring user interaction at that level, that's why it doesnt work...

Answer (score 1):

if this is the file(i downloaded and i got 25.7mb) to play Its working for me.
I used this code

```
<audio controls="controls">
    <source src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B1gAlyxjlHyaZldJTUZsTWwybGM">
 </audio>
```

let me know if you have any problems/doubts.
Thank You.